# How to ensure user with image in mysql with angular6

Tags: java, mysql, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I'm trying to create new user. i want to send user information with image to mysql database. I'm sending a user object with form data .
this is my component.ts

```
subscribeUser() {
this.errorMessage = "";
if (this.subscribeForm.invalid) {
  this.errorMessage = "cannot create user with empty fields";
  return;
}
this.userService.createUser(this.user, this.selectedFile)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
 }
   public onFileChanged(event) {
console.log(event);
this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
console.log(this.selectedFile);
}
```

this my service.ts

```
createUser(user: User,file : File) { let formdata: FormData = new FormData(); const userBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({"firstname":user.firstname,"lastname":user.lastname,"mail":user.mail,"password":user.password})],{ type: "application/json"});formData.append('file', file); formData.append('user', userBlob);return this.http.post<User>(AppSettings.APP_URL + "/users/new", formData,{responseType:'text' as 'json'});}
```

this is my controller.java

```
@PostMapping(value="/",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,"multipart/form-data"}))
public ResponseEntity createUser(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("user") User user) throws IOException {

    if(user == null){
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("cannot create user with empty fields");
    }
   
    User createdUser = userRepository.save(user);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(createdUser);
}
```

this is my component.html

```html
  <form [formGroup]="subscribeForm" (ngSubmit)="subscribeUser()" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Nom</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" [(ngModel)]="user.firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Nom" formControlName="nom">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Prénom</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" [(ngModel)]="user.lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Prenom" formControlName="prenom">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput3">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mail" [(ngModel)]="user.mail" placeholder="Email" name="mail" formControlName="mail" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput4">Password</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="file" [(ngModel)]="user.photo" (change)="onFileChanged($event)"></div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

I get this error

> "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported"

Thank you

Comment: You don’t seem to be doing anything with uploadImageData?

Comment: in the service the return request don't accept uploadImageData

Comment: You need to do all your data with formdata.append..

Comment: i updated my code and i have a new error

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider changing image type from File to BLOB.

And in REST Controller you can treat it as MultipartFile

Edit: the error you get

> "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported"

I think it's your header mime type (see this [mime type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) )

Comment: Thanks, i find a solution and i update the code